# Generate a PDF (with text & images) from a plist file, can it be done?

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf, uiview, quartz-graphics

**Background:**

My app saves user-inputted information into plist files. When a photo is taken, or selected from the library, the photo is saved as NSData to the plist as well.

I want to take the information contained in the plist files and generate a PDF document, including the image from NSData.

**Question:**

I've heard there is a way to generate a PDF from a UIView, is there a nice example to this, or an easy way without writing 1000 lines of C-based code?

Is it possible to design a view in Interface Builder, then use some magic code to generate a PDF from that view, using the data from a plist file?

Answer (score 0):

To generate a PDF you have to actually draw out the whole PDF, putting the graphics and text in exact places on each page. Apple's **[Drawing and Printing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)** explains how to go about it.

It's not easy, unfortunately, and I'm not aware of any magic code that will generate a PDF from a view.

Answer (score 0):

here's some "magic code" (to quote @Matt ;-) that will write a view hierarchy into a PDF:

```
#import <QuartzCore/CALayer.h>

UIView *displayView = self.view;
CALayer *layer = displayView.layer;
CGRect pageRect = displayView.bounds;
if (UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(path, pageRect, [self pdfContextDictionary]) == NO) {
  return nil; // error
}

UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[layer renderInContext:context];
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

unfortunately, it does so at screen resolution,
you can create a larger-than-screen version, then it will be a better resolution,

for nice, pretty, (and painful) PDF, see the above referenced guide

Comment: A screen capture of the visible part of a UIView saved as a PDF isn't a PDF in the sense that nearly anyone would want one.